# Error while enabling IISNET45

Tags: powershell, iis

I am running powershell scripts to install IIS. Below is my script

```
Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET
Add-WindowsFeature NET-HTTP-Activation
Add-WindowsFeature Telnet-Client
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServer
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpErrors
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpRedirect
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpLogging
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-LoggingLibraries
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestMonitor
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpTracing
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Security
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestFiltering
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Performance
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerManagementTools
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Metabase
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-BasicAuthentication
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WindowsAuthentication
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-StaticContent
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-DefaultDocument
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationInit
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIExtensions
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIFilter
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpCompressionStatic
Add-WindowsFeature  Web-Scripting-Tools
Add-WindowsFeature MSMQ
Add-WindowsFeature msmq-server, msmq-triggers
Add-WindowsFeature  Web-Ftp-Server
```

I get error

**Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : One or several parent features are disabled so current feature can not be enabled.
At C:\SetupScripts\Install-IIS.ps1:34 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand**

What am i doing wrong here? Sure something is wrong?

Comment: Install all latest patches via Windows Update and try again.

Answer (score 14):

Try to add option -All at the end. The All parameter enables all parent features of the specified feature before enabling the specified feature. The parent feature will be enabled with default values

```
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45 -All
```

Also please refer 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 3):

You will get it done by adding below in your script

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, and found that I had to install `IIS-ISAPIExtensions` and `IIS-ISAPIFilter` before installing `IIS-ASPNET45`. In other words:

```
...

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIExtensions
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIFilter
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45

...
```

I don't know of any easy way to find the parent feature of another feature. It would have been nice if it was a property on the objects returned from `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue like this previously. I solved it by simply by running `PowerShell as Administrator`. Even after running from elevated PowerShell,if it still throw an error then please try this

`Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools`

- Make sure you run this script from an Admin Prompt!
- Make sure Powershell Execution Policy is bypassed to run these scripts:
- YOU MAY HAVE TO RUN THIS COMMAND PRIOR TO RUNNING THIS SCRIPT

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process`

Comment: what line i should remove to add your line?

Comment: @Happy the line i provided can be included on top of your script. It will completely install the `IIS Management Tools package`.

Comment: i already run this script Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process